# Proper Use of EntityDefinition, FieldDefinition objects' DeveloperName, DurableId, and QualifiedApiName fields

Tags: metadata, object

Please help me understand the SF documentation and the proper use of these fields, in terms of accurately identifying an instance of an [`EntityDefinition`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm) or [`FieldDefinition`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm) object.

The use of the word "unique" in the documentation, for these 3 fields, is somewhat confusing.

### Use Case

I extract and sync my Salesforce object metadata in an external database. I need an immutable unique identifier for my `EntityDefinition` and `FieldDefinition` objects, and unlike other objects, the `Id` field on these objects is not a unique identifier.

### DurableId

This seems like the right field to use. The documentation for this field on both objects' pages states:

> **Unique identifier** for the field. **Always retrieve this value before using it**, as the value ***isn’t guaranteed to stay*** the same from one release to the next. To simplify queries, use this field.

Across releases then, the object's `DurableId` value is mutable?

And the phrase "always retrieve this value before using it" confuses me.

If I have the following FieldDefintion object stored in my database:

`DurableId` = `Account.00N5e000007f9gt`

unless I know that no 'release' has occurred since I last extracted metadata, there's no guarantee that the same object in Salesforce has the same `DurableId`?

If that's true,  then it seems that the unique identifier for a `FieldDefinition` or `EntityDefinition` object is the **DurableId **PLUS** some form of Api version number**, or am I not understanding what a release is?

### DeveloperName

The **FieldDefinition.DeveloperName** definition states:

> "The **unique** name of the object in the API"

Will `EntityDefinitionId + DeveloperName` give me an immutable unique identifier for a FieldDefinition object?

### QualifiedApiName

> "A **unique** external name for the field"

When evaluating the `FieldDefinition` object's data, I did some data profiling of my extracted metadata and the combination of **`EntityDefinitionId + QualifiedApiName`** gave me a unique record.

So maybe those two fields will work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metadata objects behave a little differently than data objects, as I believe they are virtual tables exposing some memory structure, hence the typical 'mental model' that we build (for ex., id is unique), which works for most data objects, may not work for metadata objects.

About `DurableId`, ignore the term "durable" and assume it is just some internal id they are exposing which will be unique unless they push a new release. So they are saying, do not store externally but you can safely use this within a transaction to build some references to link records.

`QualifiedApiName` is the object/field name that user specifies and it stays same unless a user updates the metadata, to rename the object/field. So I would use `EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName` + `FieldDefinition.QualifiedApiName` as the absolute unique way to identify a field.

Some data for reference

```
SELECT EntityDefinition.DurableId, EntityDefinition.DeveloperName, EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName,  
DurableId, DeveloperName, QualifiedApiName
FROM FieldDefinition where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName = 'App_Log__c'
```

[image]